# Typescript map object to array with new objects, according to fields

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object with some concrete fields:

```ts
 const obj1: Obj = {  
    hello: true, 
    second: false, 
    third: 311,  
    fifty: 50  
    .....  
}
```

I need to map some fields from this object to concrete number, (and use it value) and return array with it:

```ts
interface ArrayItem {
    index: number;
    visible: boolean;
}

// hello should be mapped to 3, and visible - 'true'
// result is:
const arr: ArrayItem[] = [{index: 3, visible: true}]
```

For concrete field. e.g. if obj1, has field "hello", result will be:

```ts
[  
    {
     index: 3  
     visible: (value of 'hello', so -> true)  
    }  
]
```

More examples:

```js
 const obj1: Obj = {
    hello: true,
    second: false,
    third: 311,
    fifty: 50
    .....
}
```

// fields, which i looking:

```ts
const mapped = {
    hello: 3, // index value
    second: 5 // index value
}
```

output:

```js
[
    {
     index: 3
     visible: (value of 'hello', so -> true)
    }
    {
     index: 5
     visible: (value of 'second', so -> false)
    }
]
```

Comment: So you want to parse `Obj` into new one only with `index` and `visible ` keys, don't you?

Comment: that's correct. But depends on concrete fields. e.g. i know, that "hello" field will be transformed to 3.

Comment: Ok and how about `Obj` it must contains `hello` and `second` fields with booleans? And will any other keys affect on `ArrayItem`?

Comment: yes, they boolean. Obj has any other fields, which i do not need to handle. I have map with concrete fields which i need to map e.g. 

const maps = {
 hello: 3,
 second: 4
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's declare type definition of Obj

```js
type Obj = { [key: string]: boolean };
```

Object with many key, and bool on all values.

Array items look like this:

```js
interface ArrayItem {
    index: number;
    visible: boolean;
}
```

But we can get some more knowledge about types based on values from `Obj`. To declare that let's write `InterfaceParser` generic.

```js
type InterfaceParser<T extends Obj> = {
  index: T['hello'] extends true ? 3 : number;
  visible: boolean;
}
```

`T extends Obj` means that input type must be at least `Obj`. `extends true ? 3 : number` means that when hello key is true the type of index is not `number` is `3`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Obj%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20boolean%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ArrayItem%20%7B%0D%0A%09index%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%09visible%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20InterfaceParser%3CT%20extends%20Obj%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20index%3A%20T%5B'hello'%5D%20extends%20true%20%3F%203%20%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20visible%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20map%20%3D%20(obj%3A%20Obj)%3A%20InterfaceParser%3CObj%3E%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0D%0A%20%20index%3A%200%2C%0D%0A%20%20visible%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%7D))

[Playground2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20obj1%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20hello%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20second%3A%20false%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20third%3A%20311%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fifty%3A%2050%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20mapped%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3Astring%5D%3A%20number%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20hello%3A%203%2C%20%2F%2F%20index%20value%0D%0A%20%20%20%20second%3A%205%20%2F%2F%20index%20value%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20output%20%3D%20Object.keys(mapped).map(key%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20index%3A%20mapped%5Bkey%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20visible%3A%20!!obj1%5Bkey%5D%2C%0D%0A%7D)))

Comment: thanks @Przemyslaw Pietrzak, but seems its not what i need. I updated main topic, have a look please.

Comment: To be honest i don't understand where is problem. I thought you want to have typed some values (e.g. 3 instead of number when 'hello'). Could you elaborate more, or give more exaples?

Comment: Updated topic. See below "More examples:" @Przemyslaw Pietrzak,

Comment: I think you're looking for something like: click `Playground2` link